# Django : HTML form action directing to view (or url?) with 2 arguments

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

Started learning django about a week ago and ran into a wall. Would really appreciate any enlightenment...

models.py

```
class data(models.Model):
    course = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course
```

html

Converted the objects in models.course to schlist

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/chosen/chosen.css' %}" />
<form action={% views.process %}  method="GET">
      <div>
        <h4 style="font-family:verdana;">First Course: </h4>
        <select data-placeholder="Course" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" tabindex="7">
          <option value=""></option>
          {% for item in schlist %}
          <option> {{ item }} </option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      </br>
      <div>
        <h4 style="font-family:verdana;">Second Course:</h4>
        <select data-placeholder="Course" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" tabindex="7">
          <option value=""></option>
          {% for item in schlist %}
          <option> {{ item }} </option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      </br>
  <input type="submit" value="Compare!" />
</form>
```

urls.py (having my doubts if this works..)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(\d+)/(\d+)$',views.process, name = 'process'),
]
```

view.py

```
def process(request,q1 ,q2):
    obj1= get_object_or_404(Schdata, course = q1)
    obj2= get_object_or_404(Schdata, course = q2)
 ........
```

Was wondering if it is possible for the form action to direct the action to

(1) view.py or (2) url.py (and eventually to a view.py) with 2 arguments selected?

If so how should the form action  be? {{view ?}} or {{url ?}}. Am I missing out the definition of my arguments in my HTML?

Directing to views.py:

User input is `CharField`, could use `get_object_or_404` to get the model pk. However when defining my urls.py I would get a Noreverse error as my url arguments is the primary key.

Directing to urls.py:

Url arguments is primary key. From the way I see it, I need to magically convert my User input `Charfield` to a pk before passing it to urls.py

Is there a (or) function for `get()` in django? E.g `get_object_or_404(pk = q1 or course = q1)`?

Would really appreciate any advice. Been staring at this for hours.

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution for the above problem yet?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are trying to use the reverse resolution of urls in Django.

In your html file correct form action url to the following and method should be POST:

```
<form action={% url 'process' %}  method="POST">
```

In case you are trying to pass parameters along then use this:

```
<form action={% url 'process' request.user.id 4 %}  method="POST">
```

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 13):

*Yes i'm late but it can help others for better understanding how Django processes the request.*

**Django 3.0 pattern**

**How Django processes the request**

**Basic :**

1. First Django check the matching URL.
2. If URL is matched then calling the defined view to process the request. (Success)
3. If URL not matched/found the Django invokes error Page Not Found

**In detail reading :**

[Official Django Documentations How Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)

---

**These are your URL patterns :**

```
urlpatterns = [ path('profile/edit/<int:pk>/',views.editprofile, name='editprofile'),]
```

Third argument in urlpatterns is for if you want to change the url pattern from current to this :

```
urlpatterns = [ url('profile/edit/user/id/<int:pk>',views.editprofile, name = 'editprofile'),]
```

You don't need to redefine url pattern in all Templates where you using url name.

**For Example :**

This is my template ***profile.html*** where i used the url name instead of hard coded url.

```
<a class="item" href="{% url 'editprofile' user.id %}" >Edit profile </a>
```

---

**Solution of your problem :**

**.html**

Only use url name instead of hard coded url in your templates and pass arguments.

```
<form action={% process no_of_arguments  %}  method="POST">
```

**views.py**

Here you can process your request

```
def process(request,no_of_arguments):
```

---

**Become good django developer**

You can also use Django ModelForms for your model. 
Using model forms or simple form you can do multiple things

- Modular approach
- Write server side validation in related form instead of doing in views.py
- Readable code - Clean code