# how to write form action when programing with django

Tags: python, html, django

i want to write form action to call `newpost` function from `viwes.py` , `newpost` function has 2 arguments which are `newpost(request,myid)`, but when i tried to write
`action="{%url 'newpost' %}"` an error appears like this :

`TypeError at /newpost`
`newpost() missing 1 required positional argument: 'myid'`

how can i send this argument in form action ?
please tell me

```
def newpost (request,myid):
         blockedperson=[1]
         assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
   
         print("if1")
         print (request.POST.get('postcontent'))
         print (type(request.POST.get('postcontent')))
         while request.POST.get('postcontent'):
            print ("if2")
            if myid not in blockedperson :
                savepost=post()
                savepost.person_id= 437819147
                savepost.content=request.POST.get('postcontent')
                savepost.p_date=dt.datetime.now()
                savepost.save() 
            else :
                blocked="sorry, you are blocked, you can not share a post, for more information contact with IT on 437819147@kku.edu.sa"
                return render (request,'home.html',{'block':blocked})

         allpost=post.objects.all()
         allperson=person.objects.all()
         allstudent=student.objects.all()
         allteacher=teacher.objects.all()
         allcomp=company_rep.objects.all()

         return render (request,'home.html',{'posts':allpost , 'person':allperson,'student':allstudent,'teacher':allteacher,'comp':allcomp,'id':myid})
```

```
<form name="postbox" action="{%url 'newpost' %}" method="POST" align="center">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>shear your ideas, information, and experience...</label>
        <br />
        <textarea id="post" name="postcontent" rows="4" cols="50">

 </textarea>
        <br />
        <input  style="width: 31%;" type="submit" value="post"  name="postsubmit">
        
    </form>
```

this also my urls file , should i change in it if i add any arguments ?

```
urlpatterns = [
   
     path('' , app.views.login),
     path('newpost' , app.views.newpost,name='newpost'),
     path('signup' , app.views.signup,name='signup'),
     path('signupteacher' , app.views.signupteacher,name='signupteacher'),
     path('signupstudent' , app.views.signupstudent,name='signupstudent'),
     path('signupcompany' , app.views.signupcompany,name='signupcompany')
   
]
```

Comment: Possible answer could be found here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440962/django-html-form-action-directing-to-view-or-url-with-2-arguments

You have write action with parameters,

<form name="postbox" action="{%url 'newpost' myid %}" method="POST" align="center">

Comment: Please explain the scenario properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found here:

[Django : HTML form action directing to view (or url?) with 2 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440962/django-html-form-action-directing-to-view-or-url-with-2-arguments)

Within your html:

```html
<form name="postbox" action="{%url 'newpost' %}" method="POST" align="center">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>shear your ideas, information, and experience...</label>
        <br />
        <textarea id="post" name="postcontent" rows="4" cols="50">

 </textarea>
        <br />
        <input  style="width: 31%;" type="submit" value="post"  name="postsubmit">
        
    </form>
```

You want to change the action attribute of the form to:
`{%url 'newpost' myid %}`

```html
<form name="postbox" action="{%url 'newpost' myid %}" method="POST" align="center">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>shear your ideas, information, and experience...</label>
        <br />
        <textarea id="post" name="postcontent" rows="4" cols="50">

 </textarea>
        <br />
        <input  style="width: 31%;" type="submit" value="post"  name="postsubmit">
        
    </form>
```

Comment: i tried this but an error appears that is : 
`NoReverseMatch at /` `Reverse for 'newpost' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newpost$']` i call the newpost function like this: 

``` return newpost(request,int(myid)) ```

 and it make a problem in html page when i write the argument `myid`

Comment: my urlpatterns like this :
```path('newpost' , app.views.newpost,name='newpost')
```
is there a problem in it ?

Comment: This is an incomplete answer to an incomplete question.

Comment: @AvishkaDamdawinna on closer inspection you are right he hasn't passed myid to the actual template, but he has passed 'id' which hasn't been set within the view function so essentially the function is expecting you to pass a value into it not pass it back what is has rendered as this value is not in existance.... As far as i can understand, to check this i would focus on trying to view the id passed to the template perhaps by checking the request in browser and make sure it is whats expected and then once it is follow the procedure above

Answer (score 3):

send myid in action also as you are sending it on function

like this  **"{%url 'newpost' myid %}"**

your code will look like:

```
<form name="postbox" action="{%url 'newpost' myid %}" method="POST" align="center">
```

refer  *Now, create a polls/results.html template*: from [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial04/)

Comment: i tried this but an error appears that is :
`NoReverseMatch at /`
`Reverse for 'newpost' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['newpost$']`

i call the `newpost` function like this:
```
 return newpost(request,int(myid))
```

and it make a problem in html page when i write the argument `myid`

Comment: my urlpatterns like this : ```path('newpost' , app.views.newpost,name='newpost')```  is there a problem in it ?

Comment: Where's the myid coming from??? you're not passing `myid` to the template from the view

Comment: This is an incomplete answer to an incomplete question.\